# replace partial url with another url in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have URL need to replace partial url with another url.

Original Url
`http://oldurl/dept/it/Lists/Contract Management System/DispForm.aspx?ID=4`

I want to replace just `http://oldurl` (only)  with `http://www.newurl.com`. Rest of the url will change dynamically.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why does this need a regular expression?

Comment: Because... http://sp2013qa will change each environment.

Answer (score 0):

`Request.oldURL.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)` will return your base url string which is `http://oldurl`

```
string oldURL = "http://oldurl/bs/blabla";

string newURL = oldURL.Replace(Request.oldURL.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority), "http://www.newurl.com");
```

See more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getleftpart(v=vs.110).aspx